# Can you qualify the phrase “is attributed to” by saying “is most likely attributed to?”

Tags: grammar

A co-worker frequently uses the phrase “X is most likely attributed to Y” and it feels wrong to me. I think you have to say “X is attributed to Y” and can’t qualify it with “most likely” or anything similar.

For example, I will write “vomiting is attributed to inflammation of the gastrointestinal tract.” However, writing “vomiting is most likely attributed to inflammation of the gastrointestinal tract” feels incorrect.

Am I off base here? Thanks!

Comment: I think even 'attributed' is incorrect. Vomiting is hardly a worthy cause or result. And in the noun form, attributes are positive qualities. They could say “vomiting is caused by inflammation of the gastrointestinal tract” or “vomiting is most likely caused by inflammation of the gastrointestinal tract”

Comment: You are correct; that usage is off.

Comment: I think the word your colleague wants is [attributable](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/attributable).

Comment: Why shouldn't you be able to say "X is most likely attributed to Y"? You can where it has a passive interpretation.

Comment: attributed to someone and attributable to someone are not the same thing. One is a statement of fact and the other a statement of possibility.

Comment: @Lambie - “X is most likely attributed to Y” = Someone probably says that Y causes X. "X is most likely attributable to Y" = Y probably causes X. Or that's how I understand it. See Xanne's answer.

Comment: "Le Morte d'Arthur is most likely attributed to Sir Thomas Malory" would be fine although there might be a better way of putting it ("most probably" sounds more academic).

Comment: @StuartF — That doesn’t make sense; *Le Morte d'Arthur* **is** attributed to Sir Thomas Malory (among others). Sir Thomas Malory is most likely, among those attributed, to have written it.

Answer (score 3):

What your co-worker is trying to say is that X is most frequently attributed to Y, or most likely to be attributed to Y. The statement is about the tendency of the authors, not the nature of X.

You can say that X is most likely a consequence of Y, which is about X and Y, and not about what writers tend to do.

Comment: Yes. Perhaps OP is after “X is considered by many to most probably be caused by Y”.

Answer (score 0):

Cambridge has:

> Cambridge
> *Attribute*, verb:
> to say or think that something is the result of a particular thing:
>
> attribute something to something:
> *Her success can be attributed to three main factors*

Hence we may say *X is attributed to Y*, meaning that people believe X results from Y.
Where there is some doubt about the attribution, it seems reasonable to qualify such a definite statement by saying *X is likely attributed to Y*, meaning that there is a probability less than 100% that Y caused X.

For example, *Ill health is likely attributed to poverty* implies the possibility and probability that poverty contributes to ill health, but avoids the incorrect certainty of *Ill health is attributed to poverty*, a statement that ignores all the other causes of poverty.

Note that in legal usage, a more restrictive use of *likely* sometimes applies, meaning *more likely than not*, and therefore implying a probability of more than 50%.

> [Law Insider](https://www.lawinsider.com/dictionary/likely)
> ***Likely** means more likely than not*

Comment: No, it doesn’t work like that. If you put your sentence in the active voice, you can see that: *[Researchers] likely attribute ill health to poverty.* That’s not what you’re trying to say.